# Lsp-mode on org-mode babel

Tags: org-mode, org-babel, lsp-mode

In my quest to find ways of making emacs more snappy, I installed lsp-mode.  The main language I work with is R, and indeed using lsp-mode in .R files is much quicker than the ess built-in completion.

Lsp-mode works very well in R files, the problem is all (or nearly all) my development process is within org-mode, interactively.  I can't find a way to activate lsp-mode within the editor for the minor mode (I am not sure this is correct name for it, new to this).

Here are my tests.

1. Working normally on R files:
   [image]
2. Attempting to start lsp-mode within the minor mode editor:

[image]

3. All my lsp-mode related config:

```lisp
(use-package! company
 :after lsp-mode
 :hook (lsp-mode . company-mode)
 :bind (:map company-active-map
        ("<tab>" . company-complete-selection))
       (:map lsp-mode-map
        ("<tab>" . company-indent-or-complete-common))
 :custom
 (company-minimum-prefix-length 1)
 (company-idle-delay 0.0))
   :config
   ;;Turn on company-mode globally:
   (add-hook 'after-init-hook 'global-company-mode)

(defun efs/lsp-mode-setup ()
  (setq lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-segments '(path-up-to-project file symbols))
  (lsp-headerline-breadcrumb-mode))

(use-package! lsp-mode
  :commands (lsp lsp-deferred)
  :hook (lsp-mode . efs/lsp-mode-setup)
  :init
  (setq lsp-keymap-prefix "C-c l")  ;; Or 'C-l', 's-l'
  :config
  (lsp-enable-which-key-integration t))

(use-package! lsp-ui
  :hook (lsp-mode . lsp-ui-mode)
  :custom
  (lsp-ui-doc-position 'bottom))

(use-package! lsp-treemacs
  :after lsp)

(use-package! lsp-ivy)
```

Finally, when I try org-lsp it complains that I should specify the file name at the src, which does not make the error disappear.

Question:

- How to activate lsp-mode within the minor mode editor in org-babel?

Comment: This feature is not yet supported. There are some discussions and partial implementations. See https://list.orgmode.org/87ftb5hwqj.fsf@gmail.com/T/ and  https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/oa515n/lsp_mode_and_org_source_blocks_cc/